# I want to exclude blanks in serial numbering

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

In this [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/193ADNE_cpO2_NS4E7F8XG_3oih5EwFn7LOa2hqhvsgA/edit?usp=sharing) I am trying to make a serial numbering without counting blanks.

I have tried to use `ISBLANK`, `SEQUENCE` and `MATCH`.

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E<>""; COUNTIFS(E2:E<>""; E2:E<>""; ROW(E2:E); "<="&ROW(E2:E)); ))
```

[image]